# Do we have a tag to use with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) related questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags

While spending time with the question [AJAX POST REST call generates CORS error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219382/ajax-post-rest-call-generates-cors-error) I tried to come up with more specifying tags for the original question. A slight surprise to me was that there are no Cross-Origin -related tags in SP.SE although Cross-Origin -related questions shouldn't be too uncommon with SharePoint.

SO.SE has the tag [[cors]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors) with a description that could suit for our community too. Should we add it too, or is there already one covering this field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tag the question with it and the tag will be created. If someone in the community has a better tag that is already used, they can ask for a merge of the two terms

Comment: You are right. Kinda went the "confirm-first"-way as the general guidance instructs to avoid using non-existing tags. So thanks for confirming on this one.